# Stop all audio but the one selected (dynamically created audio elements)

Tags: javascript, audio

I've looked around on this forum a couple of days now but can't find anything that works for my precise situation. I know some javascript/jquery but I would not call myself good at this language...

I have a list with mp3-files dynamically fetched from a database, and I don't want it to be able to play multiple songs at the same time. The problem is that I don't know how to write the code for "stop all other songs except for the one connected to this playbutton when pressed". so frustrating..

my php file:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM songs");

$count = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $title = $row['title'];
    $filename = $row['filename'];

    echo '<li data-filename="' . $filename . '" class="song">
            <button class="play' . $count . '">Play</button>
            <button class="stop' . $count . '">Stop</button>'
            . $title .
         '</li>';

    $count++;
}
```

And here's my js file:

```
var count = 0;

$('.song').each(function() {
  var filename = 'songs/' + $(this).data('filename');
  var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');

  audioElement.setAttribute('src', filename);

  $('.play' + count).click(function(){
    audioElement.play();
    // I need to put something here to make all the other songs pause/reset //
  });

  $('.stop' + count).click(function(){
    audioElement.pause();
    audioElement.currentTime = 0;
  });

  count++;
});
```

Since I really don't know what to do I've just tried a bunch of things like:

```
$(this).siblings().audioElement.pause();

audioElement.siblings().pause();
```

Then I read something about stopping all of the audio before it plays the one connected to the play-button. But I don't know how to "collect" all of them so that I can stop(pause and reset) all at once.

I tried this one, but that calls for the  html5 tag so it doesn't work.

```
function stopAll() {
  var xGroup = document.querySelectorAll('audio');

  for (var i = 0; i < xGroup.length; i++) {
   xGroup[i].pause();
   xGroup[i].currentTime = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but better late than never.

In order to stop the rest of the audio elements, you have to keep a reference to them in an array.

That way, you can stop all of them when the user clicks "play" on another audio tag.

What I would do:

1. Iterate over the ".song" elements, creating an audio tag for each of
   them.
2. Add listeners to the buttons that are contained within them (no need
   for indexes, you can pass the ".song" element as a parameter to
   indicate that the search of the elements is within the ".song"
   element).
3. Store the reference of the created audio element.
4. When the user presses the play element, stop the rest of the songs
   iterating over the array of the audios references.

Hope it helps.

```js
$(function() {
  var folder = "http://www.mashuptown.com/files/",
    audioTags = [];

  function stop(audioTag) {
    audioTag.pause();
    audioTag.currentTime = 0;
  }

  function stopAll() {
    audioTags.forEach(function(audioTag) {
      stop(audioTag);
    });
  }

  function addListeners(audioTag, $song) {
    $('.play', $song).click(function() {
      stopAll();
      audioTag.play();
    });

    $('.stop', $song).click(function() {
      stop(audioTag);
    });
  }

  function getAudioTag(src) {
    var audioTag = document.createElement('audio');
    audioTag.setAttribute('src', src);
    return audioTag;
  }

  $(".song").each(function() {
    var audioTag = getAudioTag(folder + $(this).data('filename')),
      $song = $(this);

    addListeners(audioTag, $song);
    audioTags.push(audioTag);
    $song.append(audioTag);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li data-filename="dj_morgoth_never_gonna_give_your_teen_spirit_up.mp3" class="song">
      <button class="play">Play</button>
      <button class="stop">Stop</button>teen spirit
    </li>
    <li data-filename="dj_morgoth_never_gonna_give_your_teen_spirit_up.mp3" class="song">
      <button class="play">Play</button>
      <button class="stop">Stop</button>teen spirit 2
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Well I deleted all of my code and started to use the `<audio>` tag instead (and everything works), but glad someone finally answered so that I can understand better how things works :) so thank you for that! @acontell